# Multiple markers error in Eclipse (Android app)

Tags: android, eclipse, markers

I am getting errors in a program that was sent to me from a different developer.  In Eclipse, I get errors that say "Multiple markers at this line... must override a superclass method".  The "quick fix" suggestion is to remove the @override command but once I do that, I get the same error.  You can see a picture of the error at [www.theiatech.com/Mark/Eclipse_error.jpg](http://www.theiatech.com/Mark/Eclipse_error.jpg).

What do I have to do to get rid of the error so I can compile the program?

I'm using Eclipse Classic 3.7.1,
Java compliance level 1.6,
JRE6,
Android 1.6 library

Answer (score 1):

Multiple markers means that there is more than one error, breakpoint, TODO, etc. at a particular line. Even if you remove all of the errors, there could still be "multiple markers". That said, frequently a single bug in the code will cause a compiler/interpreter to report multiple errors. Start at the first reported error, find the cause and fix it. This will often remove more than one error. Repeat the "debugging" process until all errors are gone.

I would not just remove the @override. Find out why it is there. You are likely to understand the error then.

Good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Try using new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() instead Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener()

```
sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {

            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
        });
```